# Descriptive word for explosive blowing through mouth

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for a word or words to describe the following two actions, both of which are relatively common.

The first is often seen as a sign of derision or dismissal. For example, one person may offer an opinion and the other responds by a very short burst of air coming from the mouth. This is similar to a snort, but a snort is usually seen as coming from the nose.

The second is similar, but slower. It is often seen when someone is exhausted or frustrated. The mouth starts of closed at the start and the person blows for a couple of seconds.

I've been wracking my brain, and haven't been able to find the Google terms that would help.

Comment: Second one might be a sigh perhaps? Can sometimes indicate frustration or annoyance at the other person

Comment: Sounds like a literal pooh-poohing.

Comment: The first is sometimes transcribed as "Pah!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is sometimes transcribed as "Pah!"

> Used to express disgust or contempt.
>
> ‘‘Pah! They know nothing.’’

[Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pah)

The second could be "pfft"

> 1.2 Used to express a contemptuous or dismissive attitude.
>
> ‘pfft, I don't know what all the fuss is about’

[Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pfft)

Comment: I think "pfft" may well be how you'd write it in dialogue. I was hoping to find a word to use outside of dialog, in the way that one may use sight, chuckle or snort.

Comment: @CobusKruger I wondered if that was what you were after, but I couldn't think of any suitable answer! "Made a dismissive noise" perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Hissing
Scoffing
Sighing .
Cant think of better ones but I get what you have in mind I just did that before turning my computer on right now lol

Answer (score -1):

I would call the equivalent of a snort, made by the mouth, a [**raspberry**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/raspberry).

> [Merriam-Webster, if you scroll down to *More Definitions*]
>
> *informal* : a rude sound made by pushing your tongue outside your lips and blowing air out of your mouth

Or from [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/raspberry):

> **4** *informal* A sound made with the tongue and lips, expressing derision or contempt.

It gives several examples, and note that some of them do express exhaustion or frustration, not just derision or dismissal:

> ‘Clare blew a raspberry’
> ‘John looked at them with tired eyes and blew a raspberry.’
> ‘Wind stuck his tongue out and blew a particularly loud raspberry in Dragons direction.’
> ‘When she reached the fence, she stuck her tongue out at the little kids and blew a raspberry.’
> ‘Frustrated, I blew a raspberry and flopped haphazardly on the couch to face him.’

Comment: No tongue action has been identified by the original poster. "Raspberries" include a front-mouth trill that would be very distinctive compared to a simple short burst of air from the mouth. Admittedly, that may be something requiring clarification, but I don't read the snort the same way.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin Both express the same *sentiments*, just one expressed nasally and the other orally. You've interpreted the question as being about an equivalent *sound*, something which I do not get from the question as it's written. (I would find it almost impossible to think of something that sounds identical *and* expresses the same feelings.)

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to describe the sounds you're describing, like *grunting* or *huffing*. So I will instead offer a technical description of how the sound may be generated.

The first one is a [guttural sound generated by the pharynx or epiglottis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pharyngeal_consonant). Basically, the back of your mouth or throat is closing off the air supply partly or fully and then releasing air in some fashion, usually as a stop, trill, fricative, or approximate. These sounds are used in spoken languages, but can also be used to describe nonverbal expressions. One of these (/ʕ/) is described as a "[controlled rolling grunt](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2009/03/controlled-rolling-grunt.html)."

The second one could be represented as a kind of bilabial fricative because its sound depends on what the mouth is doing. Typically, the bilabial (lip) articulation constrains the blowing. One candidate is the [voiceless bilabial fricative /ɸ/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_bilabial_fricative), which can be made like an /f/ but without dental contact and constantly exhaling. It is described as "[like blowing out a match](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2014/ling115/phonetics.html)." (The extremes would be holding the /f/ sound (fffffffffffffff) and simply blowing with rounded lips.) Minimally, these are fricatives because they involve partly constraining the flow of air.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. It doesn't answer the question per se, but are great descriptions and may even be useful if I spend a bit of time with them. Thank you for taking the effort.